# Can I use select-2 tag in handlebars using a simple object?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, jquery-select2, ember-select

I have an object

```
let StatusDescriptions = {
            'A' : 'Available' ,
            'W' : 'Waitlisted' ,
            'C' : 'Closed'
};
```

which is available in the page. And I use handlebars to display the page. Can I use this object in a select-2 tag as such? I tried giving optionValuePath as 'key' 'id' etc, which I know is silly. I'm new to Ember as well. Please help.

```
{{select-2 id="myID" content=StatusDescriptions optionLabelPath="what should be here" placeholder='Choose Status' searchEnabled=false}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**: if you already installed Select 2 Ember addon... (if not, instruction below)

Your object should look like this:

```
statusDescriptions: [
  {
    id: 'A',
    text: 'Available'
  },
  {
    id: 'W',
    text: 'Waitlisted'
  },
  {
    id: 'C',
    text: 'Closed'
  }
]
```

So you can have this in your handlebar:

```
{{select-2
    content=statusDescriptions
    id=id
    value=selectedChoice
    searchEnabled=false
}}
```

In your handlebar or in your controller, you can observe or use in computed property the `selectedChoice` property. (This could be in your handlebar file:)

```
Selected: {{selectedChoice.id}} - {{selectedChoice.text}}
```

**Update2**: If you really want to use a simple object, you can convert it with a computed property. For example, this could be in your controller:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({

  statusDescriptions: {
                        'A' : 'Available',
                        'W' : 'Waitlisted',
                        'C' : 'Closed'
                      },

  statusForSelect: Ember.computed('statusDescriptions', function() {
    const statusDescriptions = this.get('statusDescriptions');

    return Object.keys(statusDescriptions).map(key =>
      Object.create({id: key, text: statusDescriptions[key]})
    );
  })

});
```

So in your template, you can use `statusForSelect` as `content`.

```
{{select-2
    content=statusForSelect
    id=id
    value=selectedChoice
    searchEnabled=false
}}
```

---

If you haven't installed Select 2 addon yet:

Yes, you can use Select 2 in Ember project, but you have to install a specific Ember addon. Most of your favourite javascript library are already ported to Ember, you can look around here: http://www.emberobserver.com

You can find here a list about Select addons: https://www.emberobserver.com/categories/select

As you see, there is an `ember-select-2` addon. In your project folder run:

```
ember install ember-select-2
```

and follow the instructions if you would like to use this package: https://github.com/iStefo/ember-select-2

However, there are more up-to-date select packages, you can try them out. One of the most popular is: http://www.ember-power-select.com/

Comment: I think what the author of the question wanted to ask was if the select-2 can render select box having **a simple object** as argument instead of an **array**. He has already installed select-2.

Comment: that means I cannot have the object as it is now, to be displayed. I will always need an object in this model. No key-value thing is possible. Is it?

Comment: Based on the Select-2 documentation, it is expect this format: https://istefo.github.io/ember-select-2/#/docs

Comment: You could have a key-value property, and you can create a computed property which is automatically convert to the select-2 format. I create a jsbin for that.

Comment: I added to the above answer the computed property, which is converting the simple object to a select-2 compatible array object.